# Based off of asymptotic growth, why would this statement be true: lg^100(n)= o(n^0.01) ? Would it be because any log is less than any exponential?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Based off of asymptotic growth, why would this statement be true: lg^100(n)= o(n^0.01)? Would it be because any log is less than any exponential?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0
$,
$\dfrac{\ln^a(n)}{n^b}
\to 0
$
for any $a, b > 0$.

From
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0
$,
we have
$\dfrac{\ln(f(n))}{f(n)}
\to 0
$
for any strictly increasing unbounded positive $f$.

Since
$\dfrac{\ln^a(n)}{n^b}
=\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{b/a}}\right)^a
=\left(\dfrac{(a/b)\ln(n^{b/a})}{n^{b/a}}\right)^a
=(a/b)^a\left(\dfrac{\ln(n^{b/a})}{n^{b/a}}\right)^a
$
setting $f(n) = n^{b/a}$
gives us
what we want.